# Flutter blue plus throwing a missing adapter error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I am trying to scan nearby devices using `flutter` and `Android`. I am using [Flutter blue plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus) library. Other scanners are getting results just fine. I have grabbed an example code from library's description and I am getting a following error.
[image]

Here's a code of mine:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    [
      Permission.location,
      Permission.bluetooth,
      Permission.bluetoothConnect,
      Permission.bluetoothScan
    ].request().then((status) {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    });
  } else {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool start;
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title, this.start = true});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      home: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
          stream: FlutterBluePlus.instance.state,
          initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data;
            return const FindDevicesScreen();
          }),
    );
  }
}

class FindDevicesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FindDevicesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Find Devices'),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('TURN OFF'),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.black,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: Platform.isAndroid
                ? () => FlutterBluePlus.instance.turnOff()
                : null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => FlutterBluePlus.instance
            .startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4)),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothDevice>>(
                stream: Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2))
                    .asyncMap((_) => FlutterBluePlus.instance.connectedDevices),
                initialData: const [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data!
                      .map((d) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(d.name),
                            subtitle: Text(d.id.toString()),
                            trailing: StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
                              stream: d.state,
                              initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected,
                              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.data ==
                                    BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
                                  return ElevatedButton(
                                    child: const Text('OPEN'),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => Text('ye'))),
                                  );
                                }
                                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                              },
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBluePlus.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: const [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children:
                      snapshot.data!.map((r) => Text(r.device.name)).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: FlutterBluePlus.instance.isScanning,
        initialData: false,
        builder: (c, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data!) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              child: const Icon(Icons.stop),
              onPressed: () => FlutterBluePlus.instance.stopScan(),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            );
          } else {
            return FloatingActionButton(
                child: const Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () => FlutterBluePlus.instance
                    .startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4)));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also have included following permissions in `AndroidManifest`

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Trying this on `Android 12`. `Android 11` was kinda working with `flutter_blue`.

Comment: Is your build target also Android 12?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan how can I check that?

Comment: You AndroidManifest should contain a section `uses-sdk` that contains your min, target and max sdk version. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Comment: I'm asking because the permissions needed for Android 12 changed and this might be the problem here